# Rules for using # sign in a custom URL

Tags: url, uri, custom-protocol, custom-url

In an HTTP URL, the hash sign (#) signifies an anchor within  a page and may only appear once.

Is this a universal rule for all URLs? If I want to implement a custom URL protocol, can I use the following as a legal URL?

`myprotocol://zoo#1/cage#30/lion#11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your own protocol you may do what ever you please. However if you want common parsers to be able to parse your URL you'll have to follow [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) You may want to take a look at [section 3 syntaxe component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-16) as for rules for using "#", "?", ":" and "/".

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to stop you implementing your own protocol, but probably not much point in re-inventing the wheel - why not just use http://zoo/?x=1&y=2   (ie the query string!) that's what it's there for :)